# Local storage android and phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I was just trying to store a value and retrieve it in phonegap and jquery via mds applaud.

```
function sendData() {
    alert("SendData function");  
    window.localStorage.setItem("LatStore",position.coords.latitude);
    var LatValue = window.localStorage.getItem("LatStore");
    $("#LastLat").html(LatValue);
```

Does the local storage work in android 2.3.5. I did compile with 2.3.3 as the target.

TIA 
Dred

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Are you having a problem? Your question wasn't very descriptive.

Comment: Sorry Mine doesn't seem to store. Maybe its the datatype or something.

Comment: 12-01 19:58:30.365: E/Web Console(27444): Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:36

Comment: Well the problem seems to be that position is out of scope in your sendData function. If you have made sendData the success callback of a geolocation query you'll need to write it as "function sendData(position) {"

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. I feel a bit doh but hey ho you are a star Simon :). I was worried that android wouldn't store but IOS would or blackberry would etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon's comment was the answer but I don't know how to make a comment an answer. I need a stackoverflow for stackoverflow.

Well the problem seems to be that position is out of scope in your sendData function. If you have made sendData the success callback of a geolocation query you'll need to write it as "function sendData(position) {" – Simon MacDonald 11 hours ago

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ => stackoverflow for stackoverflow ;) 
And this is the question/answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question